# SQL Query Pivot Data 2 rows into 1

Tags: sql, t-sql, variables, join

I am try to write a query which pivots activity data into summary rows. For example the input data is activity date, description and status of either; Start, Stop or null if it is an informative row.

This is an example of the data format:

```
ID   | ActivityID | ActivityType | ActivityDate   | Status | Activity
----------------------------------------------------------------------
701  | 26         | Start        | 02/07/13 15:16 | 10     | Run Job
728  | 26         | No Change    | 05/07/13 09:30 | 20     | Running
859  | 26         | Stop         | 22/07/13 12:45 | 30     | Error
1064 | 26         | Start        | 10/08/13 13:26 | 11     | Restarted
1524 | 26         | Stop         | 28/08/13 10:19 | 31     | Error
1785 | 26         | Stop         | 07/09/13 11:48 | 31     | Error
2205 | 26         | Start        | 17/09/13 09:05 | 10     | Restarted
2528 | 26         | Start        | 14/10/13 17:56 | 11     | Restarted
2528 | 26         | Stop         | 25/10/13 20:47 | 32     | Completed
```

And this is the expected result:

```
ActivityID | Start_Type | Start_Date | Start_Status | Start_Activity | Stop_Type | Stop_Date | Stop_Status | Stop_Activity
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
26 | Start | 02/07/13 15:16 | 10 | Run Job   | Stop | 22/07/13 12:45 | 30 | Error
26 | Start | 10/08/13 13:26 | 11 | Restarted | Stop | 28/08/13 10:19 | 31 | Error
26 | Start | 17/09/13 09:05 | 10 | Restarted | Stop | 25/10/13 20:47 | 32 | Done
```

I want to get all the starts and put the corrosponding stop in the same row as activity_start_date etc. and activity_stop_date.

My problem is I want the first stop after each start which I have done, but I want to also ignore a start that has a start before it. For instants Start, Stop, Stop, Start, Start, Stop, Start would return; Start Stop, Start Stop, Start null.

I have tried a left join to join the 1st stop after a start but this also includes the second start matching the same stop twice.

I thought I needed a temp table but I think this is unnecessary. Would a date variable work where the first start sets the variable then the stop is the first stop after the variable which sets the variable and the next start is the first start after the new set variable?

Your help is appreciated!

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT
activity.ID,
activity.ActivityType                               AS StartActivityType,
activity.ActivityDate                               AS StartActivityDate,
activity.Status                                     AS StartStatus,
activity.Activity                                   AS StartActivity,
activity2.ActivityType                              AS StopActivityType,
activity2.ActivityDate                              AS StopActivityDate,
activity2.Status                                    AS StopStatus,
activity2.Activity                                  AS StopActivity

FROM tempdb..#TempTable activity

FULL OUTER JOIN #TempTable activity2
ON activity.ID = activity2.ID
AND activity2.ActivityType = 'Stop'
AND (activity2.ActivityDate > activity.ActivityDate)
AND (activity2.ActivityDate = ( SELECT MIN(activity3.ActivityDate)
FROM         tempdb..#TempTable activity3
WHERE activity.ID = activity2.ID
AND activity3.ActivityType = 'Stop'
AND activity3.ActivityDate > activity.ActivityDate))
WHERE activity.ActivityType = 'Start'

--does not have a start before
AND activity.ActivityDate > (   SELECT MAX(activity3.ActivityDate)
FROM tempdb..#TempTable activity2
                        WHERE activity2.PathwayID = activity.ID
                        AND activity2.ActivityType IN ('Stop','Start')
                        AND activity2.ActivityDate > activity.ActivityDate))

--AND activity2.ActivityDate != LAG(activity2.ActivityDate) OVER (ORDER BY activity.ActivityDate),
--AND activity.ActivityDate IS NULL

ORDER BY activity.ID ASC
```

Comment: have you tried using PIVOT-function? 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I don't think that will work as I only want the first stop date after the start ignoring all starts which previously have a start.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: What does your table and expected result look like?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The table has the following columns; `ID, ActivityID, ActivityType (Start, Stop or No Change), ActivityDate, Status, Activity`.
Expected result to look like: `ID, ActivityID, Start_ActivityType, Start_ActivityDate, Start_Status, Start_Activity, Stop_ActivityType, Stop_ActivityDate, Stop_Status, Stop_Activity`.
If an activity ID has Start, Stop, Start, Stop, Start it would return 3 rows. The first start & stop, the second and the final with the start and nulls for stops. Does that make sense?
Also, I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP2) - 10.0.4000.0 (X64).

Comment: I have edited the question to include my table data and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from #TempTable a1
cross apply
(
select top 1 *
from
#TempTable a2
where
a2.ActivityType = 'Stop'
and a2.ActivityID = a1.ActivityID
and a2.ActivityDate > a1.ActivityDate
order by
a2.ActivityDate
) a2
where
a1.ActivityType = 'Start'
order by
a1.ActivityDate;
```

You have some oddities in your data that I do not understand, but this should get you 90% there and it's much cleaner than trying to join back on ActivityDate.

Answer (score 0):

The query of shriop is almost correct, it fails where there are following rows with `ActivityType = 'Start'` like 2205 and 2528. For those the duplicated rows (the rows with the same ActivityType of the precedent) need to be dropped.

If the OP uses SQLServer 2012 or better this can be done using `LAG`

```
WITH DATA AS (
  SELECT ActivityID
       , ActivityType
       , ActivityDate
       , Status
       , Activity
       , LastActivity = LAG(ActivityType, 1, 'Stop') OVER (ORDER BY ActivityDate)
  FROM   Table1
  WHERE  ActivityType IN ('Start', 'Stop')
)
SELECT a1.ActivityID
     , Start_Type = a1.ActivityType
     , Start_Date = a1.ActivityDate
     , Start_Status = a1.Status
     , Start_Activity = a1.Activity
     , Stop_Type = a2.ActivityType
     , Stop_Date = a2.ActivityDate
     , Stop_Status = a2.Status
     , Stop_Activity = a2.Activity
FROM  DATA a1
CROSS apply (SELECT top 1 *
             FROM   Table1 a2
             WHERE  a2.ActivityType = 'Stop'
               AND a2.ActivityID = a1.ActivityID
               AND a2.ActivityDate > a1.ActivityDate
             ORDER BY a2.ActivityDate) a2
WHERE a1.ActivityType = 'Start'
  AND a1.LastActivity <> a1.ActivityType
ORDER BY a1.ActivityDate;
```

Otherwise LAG can be simulated by row numbering and self join